# Basic Oracle trigger not working

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm pretty inexperienced with sql, and I have a very basic trigger. Basically, I want to ensure that TOTAL is set to 0 when a record is first inserted. Total is a NUMBER(9,2)

```
 create or replace trigger TOTAL_INIT before insert on BILL For each row
 Begin
   :NEW.TOTAL := 0;
 end;
```

When I insert, it doesn't set TOTAL to 0, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Any compilation errors? You can obtain the compilation errors by executing `select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS where NAME = 'TOTAL_INIT'`. Also, are you committing the transaction?

Comment: how looks your BILL table? post create script with constrains

Comment: SQL Developer doesn't show any errors on the trigger, and that query returned nothing.

Comment: Due to various reasons, I can't show the specifics of the tables I'm working on. The BILL table here is an analogous situation to what I am working on. The column is not nullable. There is a data default of 0.00 set and no other triggers. There are no other constraints on that column.

Comment: If the table has a default value of 0 and the trigger fires before insert, then it doesn't really much matter.  It would matter if you were updating, though.  A default on a column executes like a before trigger, so it may be that it is firing and you don't notice.  Is TOTAL a character (I hope not)?

Comment: Are you sure that trigger compiled?

Comment: @TGray total is a Number(9,2)

Comment: @Mihai Yes, Sql developer displays the trigger without any errors and it gave a "trigger compiled" messages when I first created it

Comment: Than I`m stumped,I have no idea why it doesnt work,as it is it should

Comment: I'm confused what NUMBER(9,2) has to do with it.  On your insert, what is being stored in the table?  If it's NULL, then there's a problem.  If you are expecting decimals after 0, you won't get them as oracle doesn't store 0000000.00.  It stores 0.

Comment: I mentioned Number(9,2) because you asked if Total is a character. When I insert a non 0 number such as "123", it stores 123 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
alter table bill modify total number(9, 2) default 0;
```

Admittedly, this is not *exactly* the same.  Your code would override a value supplied explicitly, whereas this sets the value to 0 when no explicit value is supplied.

However, a trigger may not be necessary for the functionality you want.

Comment: The default is already 0. We want this trigger to ensure that the initial value will always be 0, regardless of what anyone attempts to put into it.

Comment: Are people inserting data via SQL Plus or SQL Developer?  If it's purely programmatic then you shouldn't need anything.

Comment: Data is primarily being inserted via a web application, but there may be people inserting it via a script through SQL Developer